# Ubuntu on VirtualBox on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, virtualbox

OK I am a complete computer science newbie here - purchased "Practical Computing for Biologists" to learn and first thing they have you do is set up Ubuntu on VirtualBox within Windows to allow access to Unix command line - seems a bit of a steep learning curve since I do not know what any of that means yet, but...

Anyway, I managed to install VirtualBox and download Ubuntu - when trying to set-up virtual machine, I get stuck at several steps - any pointers?

Comment: On which point did you struck?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu to virtual box is really simple.  There's thousands of videos out there on how to do it.

This one is good, and easy to follow: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WiiswmOH1Q

In the event that the above video is removed, I used this search to get to it: [http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=install+ubuntu+in+virtualbox&filters=year&lclk=year](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=install%20ubuntu%20in%20virtualbox&filters=year&lclk=year) At the time of post, the video was the first result.

Good luck and have fun with Linux!

Answer (score 0):

[The urls will need to have http:// added to the front of them. Since I'm a guest I cannot post more than 2 urls.]

[It should be noted that when using virtualbox for the first time you will receive some prompts within the vm screen regarding mouse input and things like that, these are straight forward, but not included in the below steps because my system is set to "don't display again", the prompts simply require you to click the [x] or click on the prompt, choose "don't display again" and then click the [x].]

[Depending on your hardware you may wish to use different settings than I did for the virtual machine, especially in the case of ram settings.]

**Install VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406 X86-64 On Windows 8 - Core X86-64:**

Step #1 = Download "VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406 X86-32 & X86-64" from:

"download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.6/VirtualBox-4.3.6-91406-Win.exe".

Step #2 = Download "Extention Pack For VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406" from:

"download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.6-91406.vbox-extpack".

Step #3 = Install VirtualBox and import the extention pack as depicted in the following screenshots.

s12.postimg.org/8leh0oskd/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_1.png

s12.postimg.org/zcuozc42l/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_2.png

s12.postimg.org/oxoiqf6vx/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_3.png

s12.postimg.org/53bnvs6fx/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_4.png

s12.postimg.org/emgrbi4kd/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_5.png

s12.postimg.org/3uj6wep3x/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_6.png

s12.postimg.org/czmycj34t/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_7.png

s12.postimg.org/wsz258gil/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_8.png

s12.postimg.org/3vojc31jx/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_9.png

s12.postimg.org/ki63l5uhp/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_10.png

s12.postimg.org/gczsczm3h/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_11.png

s12.postimg.org/867slew0t/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_12.png

s12.postimg.org/r3neynzq5/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_13.png

s12.postimg.org/4u9hs449p/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_14.png

s12.postimg.org/zafeq8pst/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_15.png

s12.postimg.org/hmxls1fvh/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_16.png

s12.postimg.org/hul8ojqu5/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_17.png

s12.postimg.org/t5shqnn31/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_18.png

s12.postimg.org/v6efxqtul/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_19.png

s12.postimg.org/qafejsj31/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_20.png

s12.postimg.org/gbufxb9nh/V4_3_6_91406_X8664_W8_CX8664_21.png

**Install Ubuntu 13.10 - Desktop X86-64 In VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406 X86-64:**

Step #1 = Download "Ubuntu 13.10 - Desktop X86-64" from:

"releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso".

Step #2 = Create a new virtual machine in VirtualBox, install Ubuntu, make a snapshot (optional), install guest addons (optional), and create a snapshot (optional) as depicted in the following screenshots.

s8.postimg.org/cpi0f6gyt/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_33.png

s8.postimg.org/4g650rn8l/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_34.png

s8.postimg.org/7bj87mr8l/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_35.png

s8.postimg.org/dzp0lppid/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_36.png

s8.postimg.org/4l9wafujp/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_37.png

s8.postimg.org/gd2cyzejp/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_38.png

s8.postimg.org/dqi94axyd/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_39.png

s8.postimg.org/htdvh4hgl/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_41.png

s8.postimg.org/i3le0gw2t/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_42.png

s8.postimg.org/dyahejyat/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_43.png

s8.postimg.org/xjyyar0px/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_44.png

s8.postimg.org/qi10ojx45/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_45.png

s8.postimg.org/48n3i01np/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_46.png

s8.postimg.org/ix2l6trhh/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_47.png

s8.postimg.org/ncgeycehx/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_48.png

s8.postimg.org/xqh8rkz8l/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_50.png

s8.postimg.org/p0k5qqhr9/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_52.png

s8.postimg.org/u5ld8cup1/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_53.png

s8.postimg.org/vn6tjwzfp/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_54.png

s8.postimg.org/muug9z3ol/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_56.png

s8.postimg.org/xb5yykdb9/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_57.png

s8.postimg.org/uwiorvmg5/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_59.png

s8.postimg.org/8w2cb93s5/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_61.png

s8.postimg.org/rlpqe9751/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_62.png

s8.postimg.org/ymdq718x1/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_63.png

s8.postimg.org/vtkin08kl/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_64.png

s8.postimg.org/5y5dhjw4l/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_65.png

s8.postimg.org/6za7kf2hx/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_66.png

s8.postimg.org/47mcg2elh/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_67.png

s8.postimg.org/wjchqunvp/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_68.png

s8.postimg.org/893flq6w5/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_69.png

s8.postimg.org/izr27ekit/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_70.png

s8.postimg.org/dyjo61d2d/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_71.png

s8.postimg.org/nzoifcq5h/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_72.png

s8.postimg.org/o6ytq0dwl/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_74.png

s8.postimg.org/txp03qlwl/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_75.png

s8.postimg.org/mogr6vujp/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_77.png

s8.postimg.org/p8gzeq7hh/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_78.png

s8.postimg.org/4aatgn7mt/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_79.png

s8.postimg.org/fcfwf31ph/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_80.png

s8.postimg.org/4qw132vdx/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_81.png

s8.postimg.org/c9f6bpmqt/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_82.png

s8.postimg.org/6jyxregkl/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_83.png

s8.postimg.org/bzhb383tx/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_85.png

s8.postimg.org/e6bwgadet/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_87.png

s8.postimg.org/rd6ecxffp/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_88.png

s8.postimg.org/5msiij52d/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_89.png

s8.postimg.org/wd3ukvl2d/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_90.png

s8.postimg.org/cgbph56cl/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_92.png

s8.postimg.org/qs4edj3ad/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_93.png

s8.postimg.org/93cnlwrj9/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_94.png

s8.postimg.org/rl380x55x/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_95.png

s8.postimg.org/tftunvwbp/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_97.png

s8.postimg.org/yuxzb3yhx/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_98.png

s8.postimg.org/5dd0t0fol/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_99.png

s8.postimg.org/77pvar2p1/U13_10_DX8664_V4_3_6_91406_X8664_100.png

DONE.

Comment: As this may answer the question it is not a good fit to our site. As soon as your links to the screenshots will not work anymore your post will be entirely useless. Posting screenshots requires registration, and a [minimum reputation of 10](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user). In case they are not your own screenshots you need to follow their licence policy.